# How can I pull k2 items into my custom components view?

Tags: php, oop, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-k2

I am working on a custom joomla component and have a single view setup. I am trying to figure out how to pull a list of k2 items into the view based on a few custom filters...

In *weird* english it would something like this:

Get all k2 items that_match_some_requirements into my custom components view where user_id = this user

It would be nice to be able to reference the item data normally like so:

```
$this->item->info
```

I am really just trying to understand / figure out the best way to import k2 item's and their object into my components view. If that makes sense?

Maybe something with this? Although I feel the name indicates otherwise :-/

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_component/models'); 
$whateverModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('something', 'something'); //? not sure
```

or maybe from this module code?

```
require_once (JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'route.php');
require_once (JPATH_SITE.DS.'components'.DS.'com_k2'.DS.'helpers'.DS.'utilities.php');

class modK2ContentHelper
{

public static function getItems(&$params, $format = 'html')
{

    jimport('joomla.filesystem.file');
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
    $limit = $params->get('itemCount', 5);
    $cid = $params->get('category_id', NULL);
    $ordering = $params->get('itemsOrdering', '');
    $componentParams = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_k2');
    $limitstart = JRequest::getInt('limitstart');
```

Thank you!

Comment: Note: the K2 Content module is able to do this...

Comment: Whenever I need any kind of K2 data in another extension I use the method from the K2 Content module.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating just a bit further? Thanks btw!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier your second option. Actually the whole process of getting K2 items with specific conditions is specified in the `helper.php` file.

In line 261:

```
            $items = $db->loadObjectList();
```

The objects are loaded after the query has been created (the code is too long to be pasted here).

In the next lines you can see how a lot of item properties are created, modified or generated (300 lines of code).

At the end you get an array of items (php objects):

```
                ...
               $rows[] = $item;
        }

        return $rows;
        ...
```

You could just take this file and reuse the code, or even call it from your component assuming always that the module is installed.

Comment: I am not sure I follow? In my VIEW I should require/include the helper.php from the k2 MODULE? Or should I include the module helper.php into my components controller?